# Проблема в создании матрицы, list index out of range

Tags: python, массивы, python-3.x, матрицы

Есть задача:"Сформировать матрицу из чисел от 0 до 999, вывести ее на экран. Посчитать количество двузначных чисел в ней."
Пытаюсь задать матрицу.Выбивает ето: **a[i][j]=int(a[i][j]) IndexError: list index out of range** Как исправить?. Большое Спасибо!

```
import random
a=[]
for i in range(10):
      for j in range(10):
            a[i][j]=int(a[i][j])
            a.append(random.randint(0,999))
            count=0
            if(10 <= a[i][j]<= 99):      
                count += 1

print(a)
print('количество двузначных чисел',count)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если честно, у вас написано что-то *очень* странное.

Код `a = []` создаёт список, а из условия предполагается, что это будет матрица (т.е. список списков). Матрицу 10×10 из нулей можно сформировать используя генератор:

```
a = [[0]*10 for i in range(10)]
```

Теперь к её элементам можно обращаться как `a[i][j]`. Далее, с её обходом всё понятно, два вложенных цикла. Здесь всё хорошо. Зато из вашего кода совершенно не ясно, что вы хотели сделать с каждым элементом:

```
a[i][j]=int(a[i][j])
```

берёт с позиции `[i, j]` матрицы `a` величину, преобразует к числу и сохраняет на ту же позицию. Наверное, вам нужен был какой-то другой эффект. Если предположить, что вы собирались таким образом инициализировать элемент матрицы, то теперь это не нужно, поскольку это уже было сделано. Идём далее:

```
a.append(random.randint(0,999))
```

Данная конструкция добавляет элемент в список (в его конец!), записывая туда случайное число. А это значит, что она меняет размер списка, что в данном случае неприемлемо. Если вы таким образом хотели записать в качестве текущего элемента случайное число - надо было обращаться к текущему элементу, а не создавать новый:

```
a[i][j] = random.randint(0,999)
```

Следующей строчкой вы обнуляете значение переменной `count`. Так ничего не выйдет, вы делаете это на каждой итерации цикла (а значит никогда в `count` не будет храниться ничего больше 1), и если вы хотите обойти все элементы матрицы и посчитать их количество - код обнуления счётчика надо вынести из цикла, разместив до него. С условным оператором всё хорошо.

Итак, если я правильно понял, что имелось ввиду (хотя по мне, это странная трактовка условия задачи), код получится такой:

```
import random
a = [[0]*10 for i in range(10)]
count = 0
for i in range(10):
    for j in range(10):
        a[i][j] = random.randint(0,999)
        if 10 <= a[i][j] <= 99:      
            count += 1
print(a)
print('количество двузначных чисел', count)
```

Или, если писать короче:

```
a = [[random.randint(0,999) for i in range(10)] for j in range(10)]
count = sum([1 for i in range(10) for j in range(10) if 10 <= a[i][j]<= 99])
```

Comment: Благодарю за развернутый ответ, я хотел чтоб весь процес выглядел так: выбирается число `a.append(random.randint(0,999))`, потом присвоить ему номер по `i` и по `j`,как в тру матрице,потом здесь `if(10 <= a[i][j]<= 99):` проверяется, есть ли етот елемент двухзначным.Если есть,то счетчик +1.

Comment: Для numpy массивов: `a = numpy.random.random_integers(0, 999, (10,10)); count = ((10 <= a) & (a <= 99)).sum()` (есть ещё `numpy.count_nonzero((10 <= a) & (a <= 99))` если хочется более явно намерение кода выразить).

Comment: @jfs, почему бы не добавить это в качестве ответа? Ваше решение наверняка может кому-то пригодиться. Кроме того оно будет полезно тем кто изучает NumPy...

Comment: @MaxU мой комментарий не имеет отношения к "list index out of range" вопросу (текущий ответ хорошо с этим справляется). Комментарий отвечает на вопрос: "посчитать количество двухзначных чисел в 10x10 матрице случайных чисел в диапазоне от 0 до 999 включительно". Если есть желание, то конечно вы можете этот код как ответ опубликовать или как новый вопрос и ответ, что вы считаете лучше.

Answer (score 2):

Вот здесь

```
a[i][j]=int(a[i][j])
```

У вас "a" - пока ещё пустой список []. А вы уже пытаетесь обращаться к его элементам.

И вообще, код можно написать гораздо лаконичнее, если вместо циклов использовать списковые включения:

```
from random import randint
from itertools import chain


a = [[randint(0, 999) for _ in range(10)] for _ in range(10)]

bi = [i for i in chain(*a) if 9 < i < 100]

print(a)
print(len(bi))
```

Comment: Большое спасибо! Но я пока новичек, еще до itertools не дошел)

Comment: Можно обойтись одним `for X in ..` -  `a = [random.sample(range(0, 999), 10) for _ in range(10)]`

Comment: @MaxU, только результат будет немного отличаться. sample каждый элемент последовательности использует не более, чем по одному разу. А из кода автора следует, что числа вполне могут повторятся.

Comment: @Александр, точно! я этот момент упустил...